# Wix SetProperty by feature select | Launch specific feature after installation

Tags: wix

My WixInstaller is installing two different Apps (**Editor** AND / OR **Viewer**).

After the Installation the user can check a checkbox for if he wants to launch the application.

By default, the `WixShellExecTarget`Property has the value `[#ViewerApp]`. If the user has installed the Editor, the Property should have the value `[#EditorApp]`. But it is not assigned.

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />

<SetProperty Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#EditorApp]" After="InstallExecute" Sequence="execute"><![CDATA[EditorFeature=3]]></SetProperty>
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#ViewerApp]" />
```

Comment: Try specifying `Sequence="both"` in the `SetProperty` element.

Comment: Then I get this error: `Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixAction:InstallUISequence/InstallExecute' in section 'Product:*'. SetupInstaller`

Comment: Can you specify any other action in `After` attribute instead of `InstallExecute`? Something close to it in the sequence, but present in both `InstallUISequence` and `InstallExecuteSequence`?

Comment: Mark your Property `Secure="yes"`

Comment: Then I get this error: `The Property/@Id attribute's value, 'WixShellExecTarget', cannot contain lowercase characters.  Since this is a secure property, it must also be a public property.  This means the Property/@Id value must be completely uppercase.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

Here is my solution that works:

1. define the `CustomAction` for each apllication / feature that can/should be started.

   ```
   <CustomAction Id="SetLaunchApplicationEditor" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#EditorApp]" />
   <CustomAction Id="SetLaunchApplicationViewer" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#ViewerApp]" />
   <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
   ```
2. on the last page, where the install is finished, define the start

   ```
   <Control Id="Finish" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="[ButtonText_Finish]">
       <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
       <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="SetLaunchApplicationViewer"><![CDATA[&ViewerFeature=3]]></Publish>
       <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="SetLaunchApplicationEditor"><![CDATA[&EditorFeature=3]]></Publish>
       <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication">LaunchApp = 1</Publish>
   </Control>
   ```

### !!

**If only the `Viewer` or `Editor` is installed, then this app is started. If both are installed, the `Editor` gets started, because it's `DoAction` is triggered afterwards.**

#### Exit Dialog with the checkbox

```
        <Dialog Id="HtExitDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] [Setup]" NoMinimize="yes">
            <Control Id="Finish" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="[ButtonText_Finish]">
                <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
                <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="SetLaunchApplicationViewer"><![CDATA[&ViewerFeature=3]]></Publish>
                <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="SetLaunchApplicationEditor"><![CDATA[&EditorFeature=3]]></Publish>
                <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication">LaunchApp = 1</Publish>
            </Control>
            <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="[ButtonText_Cancel]" />
            <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="[DialogBitmap]" />
            <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="[ButtonText_Back]" />
            <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="135" Y="70" Width="220" Height="20" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
                <Text>Click the Finish button to exit the [Wizard].</Text>
            </Control>
            <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
            <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="135" Y="20" Width="220" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
                <Text>{\VerdanaBold13}Completing the [ProductName] [Wizard]</Text>
            </Control>
            <Control Type="CheckBox" Id="StartApp" Width="142" Height="17" X="158" Y="120" Text="Launch Application" Property="LaunchApp" CheckBoxValue="1" />
        </Dialog>
```